# Derivative of a function in java

Tags: java

I'm facing an issue here with a java class that I'm supposed to use to display a function and its derivative.

In this case, it's supposed to be a CONSTANT :

```
public class Constant implements Formula {

private double value;

public Constant(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public double eval(double value) {
  return value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}



@Override
public Formula derivative() {
   return new Constant(0);
}
```

**and here is how i'm using it**

```
PlottableFunction function = new PlottableFunction(new Constant(1), "f");
        addFunctionAndItsDerivative(function);
```

**my function :**

```
public class PlottableFunction {
      private Formula formula;
      private String name;
      private static final double PRECISION = 0.01;
      private boolean isPlotted = false;

  PlottableFunction(Formula formula, String name) {
    this.formula = formula;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name + "(x) = " + formula;
  }

  public PlottableFunction derivative(){
    return new PlottableFunction(formula.derivative(), name + "'");
  }
```

But when I use it it doesn't display the function like it should. It returns a diagonal line in the center like the f(x)=x does, both for the function and it's derivative, instead of an horizontal line for f(x)=1 and an horizontal line above the x-axis for its derivative which of course equals 0.

Comment: Sounds like your plotting function is where the error is

Comment: Yes, if the function f(x) = 1 is drawn as a diagonal line, then your problem has nothing to do with the code which finds the derivative of f.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes it quite hard to follow. The methods in your Constant class are annotated with `@Override` but there is no super class or interface, so I'm guessing you'r implementation of the eval method is wrong.
I think, your implementatioin should be

```
@Override
public double eval(double value) {
  return this.value;
}
```

to return the constant value of your constant and not the value parameter which should be the point where the constant should be evaluated.

Comment: Well I do agree with you but I was hoping it was just a simple mistake I forgot to check. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It is a simple mistake. You're returning the parameter instead to the member of the same name. it could easily be avoided by using proper names for parameters and members.